# TPPS/2 Elan Trackpoint on Thinkpad T495 with Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu, kde, lenovo, trackpoint

I use Kubuntu 20.04 on my Thinkpad T495 with a trackpoint. The trackpoint is not working smooth even if I set the highest speed in the settings. I investigated it and tried this commands:

```
x@mx-ThinkPad-T495:~$ xinput --list-props 14
Device 'TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint':
        Device Enabled (149):   1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (151): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (295):       0
        libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (296):       0
        libinput Scroll Methods Available (299):        0, 0, 1
        libinput Scroll Method Enabled (300):   0, 0, 1
        libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (301):   0, 0, 1
        libinput Button Scrolling Button (313): 2
        libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (314): 2
        libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (305):        0
        libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (306):        0
        libinput Accel Speed (307):     1.000000
        libinput Accel Speed Default (308):     0.000000
        libinput Accel Profiles Available (315):        1, 1
        libinput Accel Profile Enabled (316):   1, 0
        libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (317):   1, 0
        libinput Left Handed Enabled (309):     0
        libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (310):     0
        libinput Send Events Modes Available (272):     1, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (273):        0, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (274):        0, 0
        Device Node (275):      "/dev/input/event12"
        Device Product ID (276):        2, 10
        libinput Drag Lock Buttons (311):       <no items>
        libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (312):       1
mx@mx-ThinkPad-T495:~$ sudo xinput --set-prop 14 'libinput Accel Speed' 1,99
```

Acceleration is better but the sensitivity is still low, the TP is too slow then too fast and my finger top hurts. I looked at many hints but can't find the right way to configure the trackpoint. I would really appreciate some hints how to do it so that it works the same smooth way as in windows. Are there no tools out the box for it?

Comment: Please report difficulties you find using Wayland as bugs to the developers at https://bugs.kde.org/. Kubuntu 20.04 developers do not recommend Wayland for regular use: see https://community.kde.org/Plasma/Wayland_Showstoppers

Comment: sorry, I use standard kubuntu 20.04 with standard windows manager. i thoughtt KDE desktop used always wayland (?). Am I wrong? it was only to clarify the setup.

Comment: Unless you've take specific steps, you're probably *not* using Wayland. Just to be sure, what is the output of `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`?

Comment: The output is "x11".

Comment: If you don't get help here, try asking at [Kubuntu Forums](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/) and [reddit/kde](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/).

Comment: There is already a bug like this in launchpad.net. I added my comments there, but the bug has been there for ages. No hope here. From 0,7 % of Linux users there are 0,1% Trackpoint users. No body is really interessted to fix the TrackPoint bahaviour. The weekness of Desktop Linux is its fragmentation and makes me maybe go back to Windows 10 with a perfect TP driver. It is really sad.

Answer (score 3):

I use Ubuntu 20.04 on ThinkPad X1 Carbon gen6.

[Installing temporary local device quirks](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/device-quirks.html#installing-temporary-local-device-quirks) which spinxz mentioned worked for me.

This is my procedure.

```bsh
xinput list-props 'TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint' | grep 'Device Node'
# Device Node (295):    "/dev/input/event17"

sudo apt install libinput-tools
libinput quirks list /dev/input/event17
# AttrTrackpointMultiplier=0.40

sudo nano /usr/share/libinput/local-overrides.quirks
```

```
[Trackpoint Override]
MatchUdevType=pointingstick
MatchName=*TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint*
AttrTrackpointMultiplier=4.0  # Higher is Faster
```

```bsh
libinput quirks list /dev/input/event17
# AttrTrackpointMultiplier=4.00
```

logout & login

Comment: Thank you for the good manual. I did the same and it worked. But I had to use this path for Kubuntu: sudo nano /etc/libinput/local-overrides.quirks and "event7". But this setting changes the acceleration of the pointer. The general sensivity itself is NOT changed by this unfortunately. So this only helps a bit for some cases when the max. acceleration is too slow. At the end the pointer movement is still not as good as in Windows. Anyway, it is a partial solution.

Answer (score 0):

With a recent libinput release this works with the magic trackpoint multiplier, called `AttrTrackpointMultiplier` and not with udev rules anymore. See the [libinput documentation on trackpoint configuration](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/trackpoint-configuration.html).

Libinput maintains hardware specific customizations, so called quirks, in `/usr/share/libinput`. See e.g. `50-system-lenovo.quirks`. Do not edit these files, they might get overwritten during the next update of the libinput packages.

To configure your overrides according to the [libinput device quirks documentation](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/device-quirks.html#installing-temporary-local-device-quirks) you have to create a file `/etc/libinput/local-overrides.quirks` and adjust the parameters accordingly. (For some distros this file might be in a different location, e.g. in /usr/share/libinput/local-overrides.quirks).

For instance, a local-overrides.quirks file according the example on the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TrackPoint#device-quirks) for changing the magic trackpoint multiplier looks as follows:

```
[Trackpoint Override]
MatchUdevType=pointingstick
AttrTrackpointMultiplier=0.75
```

Comment: It sounds very interessting. Is the instruction above enogh or shoud I ibuild libinput from git master and do all that staff before as decscribed in the first link? (I have Kubuntu 20.04.1). Can I change also sensivity of the trackpoint and not only acceeleration with this?

Comment: No need to rebuild libinput. Just use the local-overrides.quirks file. For certain distros it might be in a different location (e.g. in /usr/share/libinput/local-overrides.quirks).

Comment: thx: i see already this: /usr/share/libinput/50-system-lenovo.quirks - and there are settings for lenovo for example for the Thinkpad T490 but not for my TP T495. It is like: [Lenovo T490s Trackpoint]
MatchName=*TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint
MatchDMIModalias=dmi:*svnLENOVO:*:pvrThinkPadT490s:*
AttrTrackpointMultiplier=0.4                                                                                
Should I edit this file? How can add there my ThinkPad T495 trackpoint settings?

Comment: .... or by adding there the file /etc/libinput/local-overrides.quirks with the content above?

Comment: yes - depending on your distro this might also have to go to  /usr/share/libinput/local-overrides.quirks

Comment: I created the file with mulitiplier 1.25 in both folders, but I cannot observe any change - the sensivity of the track pont is the same. No eggect.