# In Ubuntu 23.04, How can I setup trackpoint, touchpath and mosue separattely?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, trackpoint

I have installed Ubuntu 23.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad L390.

In console, I see `libinput list-devices` show all devices, but these are not showed in de "Configuaration > Mouse and TouchPad".

I can't configure my mouse as left-hand, and my trackpoint as rigt-hand. Both share the same configuration. Before Ubuntu 23.04, I had Xubuntu 20.x and I was able to configure each device separately.

```
root@*****:/home/ruben# libinput  list-devices | grep Device
Device:           Power Button
Device:           Video Bus
Device:           Lid Switch
Device:           Sleep Button
Device:           Logitech Wireless Mouse
Device:           Logitech K540/K545
Device:           Integrated Camera: Integrated C
Device:           RAYD0001:00 2386:3118
Device:           Elan Touchpad
Device:           Elan TrackPoint
Device:           AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
Device:           ThinkPad Extra Buttons
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

see [TPPS/2 Elan Trackpoint on Thinkpad T495 with Kubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241907/tpps-2-elan-trackpoint-on-thinkpad-t495-with-kubuntu-20-04)

to get the devices:

```
sudo libinput list-devices
```

then create local-overrides.quirks:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/libinput/local-overrides.quirks
```

content like this:

```
[Trackpoint Override]
MatchUdevType=pointingstick
MatchName=*TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint*
AttrTrackpointMultiplier=4.0  # Higher is Faster
```

log out and back in to activate changes